# Source Control Manager Backend

Tags: svn, version-control

What do you think is a better approach for Source Control Manager Backend. I am weighing File system vs Hosted Subversion service.
Hosted Subversion--> (My company already has another group taking care of this)
Advantages:
* Zero maintenance on our end
* Auto-backup and recovery
* Reliability by auto-backup and file redundancy.
* File history view in built, file merge, file diff

On the other hand, while File system does not have the featured mentioned above but is much more simpler. Moreover, if files are hosted on Linux machine, which is backed up, it takes care of file system crash issues. Subversion will need working copies, which are going to be on this same Linux machine, and hence the need to not have an extra layer.

Folks, I am looking for stronger reasons why I should take Subversion instead of keeping thing simple and going with File System.

Let me know your opinions. Very thanks in advance, Gabriel.

PS: I have explored few Commercial Source Manager, and have decide to go this route as it better suits our need.

Comment: Few things to note:
1. Using Remote System Explorer by IBM to explore files at Linux machine. It takes care of the multiple developers working on the same file issue, no concurrency issues.
2. Change Back out: You can have minus revisions for file so that they are moved back to production in case of backout. You really do not need subversion for this.
3. Safety: Could be taken care by database or by unix user id permissions on the scripts which move file around in case of File system.
My point is that I have not found very convincing reason till now to NOT use File System.

Answer (score 2):

I would disagree with your statement that using a file system to store your sources is simpler. What will you do when more than one developer needs to work on the same file at the same time? What will you do when you need to back out a change? The benefits of a real source control system (Subversion or other) are many.

Answer (score 0):

I won't even bother to list the reasons. It all comes down to this:

## you're a programmer

The complexity you deal with every day dwarfs the the complexity of even the most (*caugh* git *caugh*) complex SCM.

Using the filesystem for chance control is similar to programming with notepad: it'll work for small projects, but the lack of features (and safety, etc) will very quickly start to cost you big time.

That said, I do feel bad for recommending something without science to back it up. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Use source control. Full stop.

For a list of reasons, there are ton of articles out there, but start with http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/source-control-anything-but-sourcesafe.html and for i.e. http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.14/14.06/VersionControlAndTheDeveloper/